# How to write external type record using nfctools java library?

Tags: java, nfc

I'm trying to write external type ndef record to MIFARE ULTRALIGHT cards using nfctools java library (https://github.com/grundid/nfctools), but unsuccessfully. Has anyone tried this yet?

Comment: This question is very unclear and lacking detail. Post code of what you've tried so far and anything in particular you don't understand.

Comment: I'm very sorry for delayed answer. I've posted what i've found out after searching the 'nfc tools' java library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an external type record, decoder and encoder like the [Android Application record or the GeoRecord](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools/tree/master/nfctools-ndef/src/main/java/org/nfctools/ndef/ext). Then register them using NdefContext.registerExternalType(..).